# Accessing the arrival time of an email in a handler

Tags: postfix

In my `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file I have a handler which pipes emails to an external script:

```
mytransportname   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=localuser argv=/path/to/my/script.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

In `script.py` I want access the Arrival Time of the email, i.e. the time which my Postfix server received the email.  I was hoping there would be a macro for this: `${arrival_time}`, but according to the documentation this is not the case.

I can see the arrival time by using `postqueue -p`, so I know it is stored *somewhere*.

Is there a mechanism for passing this data along to my script?

Comment: Is it not in a Received: header?

Comment: Is that header added by Postfix?  I cannot trust the clients that are sending the emails.

Comment: Yes, each SMTP server adds its own Received: header.

Comment: Ah I see that now, thanks!  I guess that answers my question!